# Не работает клиент-серверное подключение

Tags: c#, .net, unity3d, клиент-сервер

Запускаю сервер в консольном приложение и клиент в Unity, на одном компьютере все работает, если перенести клиент на телефон, то подключение не получается.
При этом, у другого человека в другой сети все отлично.
В чем может быть проблема, вероятно дело не в коде? Ниже код клиента и сервера.
Заранее спасибо! 
**Клиент:**

```
        Socket client = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        do
        {
            client.Connect("192.168.43.51", 6843);
        } while (!client.Connected);
```

**Сервер:**

```
    void Start()
    {
        Socket serverSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        Debug.Log("Ожидание подключения");
        serverSocket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 6843));
        serverSocket.Listen(5);
        Debug.Log("Listen");
        Socket client = serverSocket.Accept();
        Debug.Log("Accept");
        Debug.Log("Отправил и узнал:" + client.RemoteEndPoint);
    }
```

Comment: IP адрес точно совпадает с адресом компа, на котором запущен сервер? Ping есть?

Comment: @aepot, ip-адрес совпадает, с таким подключением, вроде, разобрался, но не пингуется почему-то
```Ping ping = new Ping();
txt.text += $"\n{ping.Send(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.43.173")).Status}";
 clientSocket.Connect(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.43.173"), 6843);```
Вот таким образом пингую.Не работает, если это два андроид устройства

Comment: Пинг не обязательно должен работать. Для проверки с компьютера можно из консоли еще пинговать. К сожалению, без детальной диагностики сети, мало что можно сказать.

Comment: @aepot, а как можно другим образом искать устройства в сети?

Comment: UPnP, NetBIOS (не помню, что из этого подойдет)